# Combine multi-dimentional data in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 1-d `NumPy` arrays which represent the points on an n-d grid. Each `NumPy` array represents points in a dimension. I want to generate a merged `NumPy` array that will have the n-d grid with a shape `(n , m)` where `n` would `len(dim-1) * len(dim-2) * ...` and `m` is the number of dimensions

For example (2-D Case):

```
In [1]: x = np.array([1, 2])

In [2]: x
Out[2]: array([1, 2])

In [3]: y = np.array([3, 4, 5])

In [4]: y
Out[4]: array([3, 4, 5])

In [5]: result = np.array([[1, 3], [1, 4],[1, 5],[2, 3],[2, 4],[2, 5]])

In [6]: result
Out[6]: 
array([[1, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [1, 5],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [2, 5]])
```

Another example (3-D):

```
In [7]: x = np.array([1])

In [8]: y = np.array([2, 3])   

In [9]: z = np.array([4, 5, 6])

In [10]: x
Out[10]: array([1])

In [11]: y
Out[11]: array([2, 3])

In [12]: z
Out[12]: array([4, 5, 6])

In [13]: result = np.array([[1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 5], [1, 2, 6], [1, 3, 6]])

In [14]: result
Out[14]: 
array([[1, 2, 4],
       [1, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 5],
       [1, 3, 5],
       [1, 2, 6],
       [1, 3, 6]])
```

Is there a way to do that easily for n dimensions without looping through each array?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just do `itertools.product(x,y,z)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.meshgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) to create the *extended* versions and then use [`np.column_stack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) on column-majored flattened versions of those, like so -

```
X,Y,Z = np.meshgrid(x,y,z)
out = np.column_stack((X.ravel('F'),Y.ravel('F'),Z.ravel('F')))
```

---

To make it generic such that it would work for any number of inputs cases, we need some additional work, like so -

```
def combine_arrays(A):
    return np.dstack(np.meshgrid(*A)).ravel('F').reshape(len(A),-1).T
```

Sample runs to test out both `2D` and `3D` cases -

```
In [67]: # 2D case
    ...: x = np.array([1, 2])
    ...: y = np.array([3, 4, 5])
    ...: 

In [68]: combine_arrays((x,y))
Out[68]: 
array([[1, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [1, 5],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [2, 5]])

In [69]: # 3D case
    ...: x = np.array([1])
    ...: y = np.array([2, 3])   
    ...: z = np.array([4, 5, 6])
    ...: 

In [70]: combine_arrays((x,y,z))
Out[70]: 
array([[1, 2, 4],
       [1, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 5],
       [1, 3, 5],
       [1, 2, 6],
       [1, 3, 6]])
```

Comment: Thanks! This works like a charm with no additional imports

Comment: @KapilSharma Check out the just added generic approach!

Comment: Ahh that's great! Thanks @divakar

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply with `itertools.product`
For instance:

```
x = [1,2]
y = [3,4,5]
list(itertools.product(x, y))
# [(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)]
```

This also works for more than two inputs:

```
a = [1]
b = [2,3]
c = [4,5,6]
list(itertools.product(a,b,c))
# [(1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (1, 2, 6), (1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 5), (1, 3, 6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a very elegant solution but it will get it done:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2])
y = np.array([3, 4, 5])

pd.MultiIndex.from_product([x, y]).to_series().apply(pd.Series).values

array([[1, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [1, 5],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [2, 5]])
```